# Can someone give me an example of how to work out an exact linear second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a theorem that states:

if an equation P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0

can be written in the form:

[P(x)y']'+[f(x)y]'=0

then the equation is said to be exact.

Now I need to expand and equate the coefficients of these equations to show that a necessary condition for an equation to be exact is...

P''(x)-Q'(x)+R(x)=0

I began to expand the second equation but I do not know where to go from there.

Comment: A satisfying condition is $R(x)=P'(x)+Q'(x)$ come from using derivative of the exact form.

Comment: This is probably going to be moved to Stakexchange (in the meanwhile you may like to equate the coefficients of what you got with those in the initial equation)

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the derivative of the the exact form gives you a satisfying condition which is $$R(x)=P'(x)+Q'(x)$$

If we want to multiply both sides in function $g(x)$ to make it exact, after writing the everything you will reach to $$R=P'+Q'+\frac{g'}{g}(P+Q)$$

Then you know how to calculate $g(x)$.